# Replace with IF Condition and LIKE statement, in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my database I have a table like this:

```
id  image_url                               house_id
1   /upload/house-id-52_myimagename1.jpg        52
2   /upload/house_id_52_myimagename2.jpg        52
3   /upload/house-id-52_myimagename3.jpg        52
```

I want to duplicate it using SQL query, but want to have image name in the image_url column always prefix with "house-id-{house_id}" this format, no matter if it is in underscore format in previous id. IT should be always dash separated for new duplicated results as shown output below:

```
id  image_url                               house_id
4   /upload/house-id-53_myimagename1.jpg        53
5   /upload/house-id-53_myimagename2.jpg        53
6   /upload/house-id-53_myimagename3.jpg        53
```

I have made a query for this:

```
INSERT INTO house_gallery (image_url, house_id) 
    (SELECT 
        IF(image_url LIKE '%house_id_%',
            replace(image_url, 'house_id_52', 'house-id-53'),
            replace(image_url, 'house-id-52', 'house-id-53')) 
        AS `image_url`, 53 AS house_id 
    FROM house_gallery WHERE house_id = 52)
```

But it is not working in case of `house-id-52`. Please check and advise what could be the solution for this, to get dashed url.

Comment: They are different, in one I am replacing `_` once and in another `-` once.

Comment: I suspect you have run into the `LIKE wildcard issue`. 1) _`image_url LIKE '%house_id_%'`_ this is true for all values of patterns which look like: _`house_id + ` `any single character`_ as the `wildcard underscore character` matches everything! Therefore the _`else`_ expression never gets executed! Alas, you only replace the exact pattern: _`'house_id_52'`_ Here the underscore is treated as a 'literal'. Hence the output is 'inconsistent'. I have run the code.

Comment: A possible answer in your case is to use the: [expr LIKE pattern [ESCAPE 'escape_char'\]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) so that you can treat the underscore and dash as literal characters. I am just trying to explain why the code didn't work as you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is same you can probably use the `substring_index` function. Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from image ;
+------+--------------------------------------+----------+
| id   | image_url                            | house_id |
+------+--------------------------------------+----------+
|    1 | /upload/house-id-52_myimagename1.jpg |       52 |
|    2 | /upload/house_id_52_myimagename2.jpg |       52 |
|    3 | /upload/house-id-52_myimagename3.jpg |       52 |
+------+--------------------------------------+----------+

select 
case 
 when 
  substring_index(substring_index(image_url,'/',-1),'_',1) = 'house' 
  then replace(image_url,'house_id_52','house-id-53') 
  else 
   replace(image_url, 'house-id-52', 'house-id-53') 
end  as modified 
from image ;
```

You will get

```
+--------------------------------------+
| modified                             |
+--------------------------------------+
| /upload/house-id-53_myimagename1.jpg |
| /upload/house-id-53_myimagename2.jpg |
| /upload/house-id-53_myimagename3.jpg |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Now lets create the other table

```
mysql> create table image_copy like image ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> describe image_copy;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| image_url | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| house_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the insert query is

```
insert into image_copy 
select 
id,
case 
 when 
  substring_index(substring_index(image_url,'/',-1),'_',1) = 'house' 
  then replace(image_url,'house_id_52','house-id-53') 
  else 
  replace(image_url, 'house-id-52', 'house-id-53') 
end  as image_url,
'53'  
from image 
where house_id = 52
;

mysql> select * from image_copy ;
+------+--------------------------------------+----------+
| id   | image_url                            | house_id |
+------+--------------------------------------+----------+
|    1 | /upload/house-id-53_myimagename1.jpg |       53 |
|    2 | /upload/house-id-53_myimagename2.jpg |       53 |
|    3 | /upload/house-id-53_myimagename3.jpg |       53 |
+------+--------------------------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```